# fire a trigger when on of my table column change

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I have a table that it name is A .
I need to add a trigger for before update and delete event but it should fire just after change a specific column of A , not all of columns.
I add this code but it does not work Correctly
and always fire from form of Oracle Apex
while this is correct when edit date from Data Base in PL/SQL Developer
, what can I do?

I use PL/SQL Developer   Version 15.0.4.2064  (64 bit)

create or replace trigger A_PRE_UPD_DEL
BEFORE
UPDATE OF col_name
OR DELETE
ON A
for each row

Comment: I use Oracle APEX 23.1.0

Comment: Seems like the issue is either in Apex or in your PL/SQL code, not in PL/SQL Developer. Can you share a test case so we can try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have a form in Oracle Apex and sumbit page ,
all columns in your page will send to server .  so we pass this condition
(UPDATE OF col_name) and trigger will be fired. if you want prevent firing  this trigger you should manage it from your form Oracle Apex.